# DDR4 vs DDR5 in setting up a ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, full-node, enode, validators

Seems that set up a validator node is quite demanding on the computer specification. ( high storage, cpu with many cores, lots of memomry required)

I was think whether DDR4 or DDR5 ram  will be a better choice?

DDR5 have higher frequency but higher latency also.

Answer (score 0):

The demands for a validating node are not high, quite the contrary. You can run both a consensus client (Prysm, Lighthouse, etc.) and an execution client (Geth, Besu, etc.) on very low-tier hardware. There are certain specifications I would not go below, but typically you would be fine with the following specs:

- Dual-core CPU with hyper threading, four cores is a plus. Intel Sandy Bridge (Core 2000) or better, AMD Zen 1 (Ryzen 1000) or better.
- 16 GB of memory, the kind that is supported by your platform (DDR3/4/5)
- 1 TB SSD or larger (not a spinning hard drive), ideally 2 TB. Geth will need to be pruned every 6-9 months on average with a 1 TB disk, less often than annually with a 2 TB disk. On a 2 TB disk you also get the benefit of being able to run Erigon as your execution client, which fits an archive node into around 1.2 TB.
- Network connectivity with at least 5 Mb/s up and down, ideally 50+ Mb/s so initial sync doesn't take forever and you can do something else on the network as well.

For reference, I validate on an [Intel i3-4150T](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/77487/intel-core-i34150t-processor-3m-cache-3-00-ghz/specifications.html). It's 8 years old, has two cores, and runs at a constant 3 GHz without turbo boost. It's paired with a 1 TB QVO SSD and 16 GB of SO-DIMM DDR3. Average CPU usage is under 50%. I run both a consensus client and an execution client.

Comment: in order to execute a transaction as fast as possible, is using your own node faster or using some cloud provider(infra, quicknode,moralis) faster?